# docker-compose vs docker run to load local docker images across the machines

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have copied the images created on one machine and copied that images on a different machine. (docker images are saved using `docker save -o [images.tar]` command)

After copying, images are loaded using `docker load` command on the second machine.

When I try to run these images using docker compose file(i.e yml file)
After execution of `docker-compose up -d --no-recreate` command 
I am getting below error,

```
Pulling mongodb (datastore-mongodb:latest)...
ERROR: pull access denied for datastore-mongodb, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

But Image is already present in local docker repo and same is verified using the `docker images` command.

However, using `docker run` command I could able to run the same image.
But I have multi-container application so I cannot able to replace yml file.

Why it is not working with docker compose?

Below is the yml file:

```
version: "2.2"
services:
    mongodb:
        image: datastore-mongodb
        container_name: datastore-mongodb
        network_mode: "bridge"
        volumes:
            - /opt/mongodb:/data/db
        ports:
            - 192.168.80.240:27017:27017
```

Comment: can you share the compose file, if that is ok?

Comment: Thnak you for the response

Comment: is your image there in docker images cache. can you check with docker iimages

Comment: yes it is there in cache and i could see it using "docker images" command

Comment: please edit the answer to include the output of your `docker images` command. Do you have DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST enabled?